# Simpler way to find most frequent, second most frequent, and third most frequent value using Maps

Tags: java

So I have this enhanced for loop that finds the most frequent, second most frequent, and third most frequent. but if I wanted the like the top 10 most frequent values. What would be the best solution instead of my way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `Map` of value → count. (It looks like you've got that down already.)
2. Build a list of `(value, count)` pairs. (hint: create a list from the map's entry set.)
3. Sort the list by `count` (descending). ([hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29))
4. Take the N first elements. ([hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29))

Answer (score 0):

If your map is large and you dont want to sort it, then use a PriorityQueue, where the priority is the ip_count. Add the ips to the queue, and if there is more than 10 elements in it, remove the last one.